# Is there a way to declare two spring beans instance from the same class with annotation only?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I usually use the XML Spring configuration (spring-conf.xml) for doing it like this:

```
<beans>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.company.dept.business" />
   ... 
    <bean id="myServiceB2B" class="org.company.dept.business.service.MyService"
        p:configLocation="WEB-INF/classes/b2b.properties" />

    <bean id="myServiceResidential" class="org.company.dept.business.service.MyService"
        p:configLocation="WEB-INF/classes/residential.properties" />
   ...

</beans>
```

Because there is only one file (definition) of the class MyService is there a way to instantiate the two beans without using the XML Spring configuration?

I am ok with the XML definition but I am always trying to minimise my XML configuration as much as possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the same way you would use 2 `<bean>` declarations in XML, you use 2 `@Bean` annotated classes in Java configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "firstService")
    public MyService myService1() {
        return new MyService();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondService")
    public MyService myService2() {
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

I don't know what the `configLocation` is for, but you can definitely include that in the Java config as well.

The `name` attribute of `@Bean` is equivalent to the `id` attribute of `<bean>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need multiple instances of a bean you must explicitly configure them either in XML or in a `@Configuration` annotated class. Either way you need some way of explicitly defining the beans, you cannot have multiple instances only by component-scanning.